# java - displaying a list

Tags: java, swing

I am still pretty new to java programming and I am wondering how would i go about creating a auto generated list of data, like this for example.

[image: the list]

Comment: See [How to use tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html).

Comment: See [Java tutorial: How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html).

Comment: Take a look at the Swing tutorial [How to use lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html)

Comment: @AndrewThompson The same link, at the same moment ;)

Comment: These kinds of questions are not welcomed here, this requres a whole book to explain this.

Comment: @Eng Great minds.. :)

Comment: Why does the comment about using a JList have more upvotes than the suggestion to use a JTable? Multiple columns of data with a heading sure looks like a JTable to me, even if the poster asked about a list. Isn't the complete saying "Great minds think alike, fools seldom differ"? ;-)

Comment: @camickr  Sometimes I fear that if the question were *"How do I shoot myself in the foot?"* the answer would come back as a clear list of instructions.  :-/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend using a [`JTable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html), then put at [`JTable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html) into a [`JScrollPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html). Which would allow you to make the [`JTable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html) larger.

[image]
<sub>(source: [javalobby.org](http://www.javalobby.org/articles/jtable/images/img8.png))</sub>

Above is a JTable example

Answer (score 1):

You can use the JTable component:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you have sevral diffent types of data, your going to need more than just a simple list to contain it all. You could have three arrays that contain one slice of information in each and then go through a for loop.

```
String[] array1;
int[] array2;
String[] array3;

for (int i = 0; i < something.lengh; i++){
   array1[i] = firstPortionOfData;
   array2[i] = secondPortionOfData;
   array3[i] = thirdPortionOfData;
}
```

This would be the simplest way to do it. But if you wanted to you could use some other complex structure or something. For displaying it, you could simply go through another for loop with similar syntax.

Hope this helps.

~Tumbler

Comment: -1, 3 arrays is not a good way to store data. Create a custom object with 3 properties.